# Auto increment an ID number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to implement a feature that whenever a record is created, it auto-generates a number starting from 1. For example, if I go onto a web page and click "Create record," I want the number to auto-populate in the record ID field. When I try to create another record,
it should start at two now and keep incrementing up from there every time a record is created. I am using HTML, CSS, and Typescript as my programming languages.

Comment: and where is your code?

Comment: Is this for a production system? If so, creating identifiers on the client side is a really bad pattern to use. They should be created server side. I'd also suggest using non-incremental values as ids, such as GUIDs.

Answer (score 0):

Creation of IDs for any type of entity should be done by server side application (when the client sends the record information(without id) using a POST request). But if you need to create a local counter for some other use case you can use below code snippet.

```
incrementCounter = (function() {
    let counter = 0;
    return function() {
        counter++;
        return counter;
    }
})();
// Usage
console.log(incrementCounter());   // 1
console.log(incrementCounter());   // 2
```

In the above code snippet, I have used an immediately invoked function expression(IIFE). It declares a counter variable inside it and returns a function which has access to that variable. Everytime the incrementCounter function is called it returns the value of the counter after incrementing it. Since the counter variable is inside the scope of the IIFE, it cannot be manipulated by the outside code.